# rewriting url with htaccess from http to https + rewriting url displayed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, model-view-controller, https, url-rewriting

I'm currently trying to setup a .htaccess file but I'm kinda struggling as we didn't learned it yet in my school.

The goal is to rewrite the http to https and change the url seen to remove the /public/ that is visible.

My folder looks like this

```
website
   config
      ~
   controller
      ~
   model
      ~
   public
      index.php
   view
      ~
```

And the server seems to be automatically sending the user from https://mywebsite.com to https://mywebsite.com/public

My htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public/(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /%1
```

So I managed to set the https. But everytime I'm trying to change the url from mywebsite.com/public/ to mywebsite.com it stays the same, I'm coming back on the root, and if I try to manually go inside the public folter I end up with mywebsite.com/public/public/ with a public/ for each try to access the folder.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?public/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with `R=302` *temporary* redirections and to only change that to `R=301` *permanent* redirections one you are satisfied with everything. That prevents nasty caching issues on the client side ...

Comment: When I'm trying your solution I'm getting a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.
I did tried that aswell yesterday with the same result :/

Comment: What are those redirects? Please check the sequence in your browser's console. The rules look okish to me ...

Comment: It goes to the root, then /public/, then the root, then /public/, etc

Comment: Please test again using a fresh anonymous browser window to prevent caching issues. If that does not work, then I suspect that you have other, additional rewritings in place which have not yet been mentioned here.

Comment: I did try to remove the cookies on my end, tried it on another browser and in anonymous mode. And the results is the same. I'm only using what you posted in my root.
I do not have access to the folders upper mine so maybe there is something causing troubles above.
Or maybe I didn't understand what I can and can't do with .htaccess.

I want to redirect to the public but not display that folder in the url. I thought I could do that with htaccess but rewritting it causes a redirection which is not what I want.

Comment: I am confused: on the one hand you say that you implemented above rules in your "root" (I assume you refer to the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of that http host). On the other hand you state "I do not have access to the folders upper mine". What folders should be further "up" than the "root"?

Comment: Also keep in mind that it might be your actual application logic that is responsible for the additional redirection.

Comment: please try to replace the `[L]` flag in the last rule by an `[END]` flag. I updated the code above accordingly.

Comment: I was persuaded that I answered. But yes adding END at the end worked, thanks!